# нехватка DLL при попытке запуска .exe приложения c++ на другом компьютере

Tags: c++

Сделал приложение в C++ при помощи MS VisualStudio 2019 под Win10. Взял из папки Debug *.exe файл. Перенёс приложение на другой компьютер (где нет MS VS 2019, тоже Win10) и вот там при запуске исполняемый файл внезапно для меня стал требовать разные DLL файлы: ucrtbased.dll, MSVCP140D.dll, VCRUNTIME140D.dll. Подскажите, можно ли как-либо настроить проект так, чтобы всё необходимое было включено в *.exe файл проекта и внешние DLL не требовались при перемещении на другой компьютер?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте собрать релизную версию, а не дебажную.

Answer (score 0):

Навкидку - есть два способа: собрать дистрибутив Вашей программы или использовать статическую линковку.

К сожалению, в C++ (в отличие от языков, более широко использующих мета информацию о типах, таких, как C#) почти вся работа по указанию зависимостей Вашей программы ложится на пользователя. ТО есть, если Вы на "первом" компьютере перечислите все нужные DLL, то он их упакует в дистрибутив.

Да и не все нужные DLL могут иметь версии, подходящие для статической линковки.

К сожалению, боюсь, мой ответ был Вам не особенно полезен...

Comment: как оказалось если произвести build не для debug, а release, то файл не требует указанных библиотек. Заработало. Спасибо за участие